# How to add an Attachment to Outlook Mail from UWP App programmatically?

Tags: outlook, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am developing an UWP Application , i want to add a Attachment to outlook from UWP app programmatically

Request you to please me know if any alternatives are there.

Looking forward for your response.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the share contract to send some data to the compliant applications (including outlook). It allows you to share some text and data with any compliant apps.

To activate the sharing, you just need to register to the DataRequested event and show the share UI:

```
DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

Then, in the event handler:

```
private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral    = args.Request.GetDeferral();

    try
    {   
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Title          = "Share Title"
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Description    = "Share some data/file";
        var file                                    = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync("myFileToShare.xxx");
        args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new IStorageItem[] { logFile });
    }
    catch
    {
         args.Request.FailWithDisplayText("Unable to share data");
    }
    finally
    {
        deferral.Complete();
        sender.DataRequested    -= OnDataRequested;
    }
}
```

Once done, the system will show the share UI where the user will be able to select the app he want. This app will receive the sent data.

Answer (score -1):

While @Vincent's answer is perfect when you want to use Share Contract, if you want to use Just Email and attach the File, Below is a simple Method that i use in one of my App.

```
internal async void ShowEmail(string body, string subject, StorageFile attachment)
{
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
    email.Subject = subject;
    email.Body = body;

    var stream = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachment);
    email.SetBodyStream(EmailMessageBodyKind.Html, stream);

    await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
}
```

Above method is a strip down of the example from [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email)

Comment: This wont work if (a) you have Outlook as default email app (or any other Win32 app) and (b) Outlook is not started previously or (c) if you try to add attachments